# Fragments giving Unexpected token error in React 16.2

Tags: reactjs, react-16

I have the following component that renders a series of components. However, I downloaded React 16.2 and tried to use fragments instead of divs, but I get the following error:

```
Error in ./src/containers/answers.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (24:5)

  22 |     
  23 | return (
> 24 |     <>
     |      ^
  25 |       {AnswersCard}
  26 |     </>
  27 |    )
```

Why am I getting this error when fragments are supposed to be able to replace divs in React 16.2?

```
  question ? 
    AnswersCard = ( question.answers.sort(function(a,b) { return (a.count < b.count) ? 1 : ((b.count > a.count) ? -1 : 0)} 
    ).map(answer =>  
    <Answer key={answer.id} answer={answer} questionId={question.id} />
    )) : AnswersCard = ( <p>Loading...</p> )

return (
    <>
      {AnswersCard}
    </>
   )
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe you have updated react 16.2 in global (-g) , not local, can u check package.json and reinstall?

Comment: i checked and it's react 16.2 in the component

Comment: You need to update your babel also https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#babel

Comment: that didn't work either. same error.

Comment: The current `react` version is 16.6 and it is supported now by all tools.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax), the syntax `<></>` is not supported by all tools and they encourage you to use `<React.Fragment>` instead

Check **[this](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax)** documentation on Support for Fragment syntax

Comment: @shubham Khatri You are life saver

Comment: Exactly you right, new `XML`/`JSX` syntax fragment, hence `<></>` needs to run with babel version **7**.

Comment: If you are using newer version of react via CRA and Gatsby. I don't think `<>` being unrecognized is still an issue. The recommended standard might have changed between this answer at in 2020.

Comment: it's still an issue in Next.js + TSX

Comment: 2023 and it's still an issue following this tutorial: https://react.dev/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe#setup-for-the-tutorial

Comment: I was also following the tutorial and switching to a newer version of `react-scripts` solved it. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455176/328817