# Unexpected token at `>` of a `<>`

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to follow [Tic-Tac-Toe tutorial on React](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/tutorial-tic-tac-toe) in my local environment. However, when I run `npm start`, I get a syntax error around `<>`.

#### How to reproduce

1. In the middle of the tutorial, under "At this point your code should look something like this:", click Fork in the upper right corner of the example code with the numbers from 1 to 9 written in a table.
2. Click the button in the upper left corner of the Code Sandbox, navigate to File, then Export to Zip, and download the code example as a Zip file.
3. Unzip the downloaded Zip file, and execute `npm install` and `npm start` in that order in the project root directory.
4. The following error message is displayed.

```
./src/App.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token (3:5)

  1 | export default function Board() {
  2 |   return (
> 3 |     <>
    |      ^
  4 |       <div className="board-row">
  5 |         <button className="square">1</button>
  6 |         <button className="square">2</button>
```

#### Question

How can I resolve this error? Although I can continue the tutorial online, I would prefer to continue it in a local environment where I can get assistance from lsp, formatters, etc.

#### Version Information

Node.js: v18.12.1

npm: 8.19.2

`npm view react version` on the project root: 18.2.0

Comment: What version of React are you using ? this is fragment https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: Change `App.js` to `App.jsx`. See also: [Writing markup with JSX](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/writing-markup-with-jsx) in the getting started documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) Short syntax "<></>" use the longhand version OR make sure you have the [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets) required for react in your Editor/IDE. There are more [here](https://codevoweb.com/top-10-best-vs-code-extensions-for-react-developers/) that help with other items like [formatting](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode).

```
import React from "react";
    
export default function Square() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment> 
             <button className="square">X</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

The LSP for JavaScript should be setup by [default](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide). For Typescript it doesn't setup one, rather consuming the [tsserver](https://github.com/typescript-language-server/typescript-language-server) directly.

Comment: This answer content is concerned with a text editor diagnostic issue, but the OP has described a runtime `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Syntax error is at runtime maybe fixed by the React.Fragment. I can't see what version of react this tutorial is using so I'm assuming the latest. I can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48596157/fragments-giving-unexpected-token-error-in-react-16-2) suggests the same workaround for Fragment. The editor setup also mentions appropriate [plugins](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/editor-setup).

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem, and I noticed that react-scripts was at version 1.0.0 in `node_modules/react-scripts/package.json` but [much newer versions are available](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts).

I made this change to my root-level `package.json` (there are two package files the main project, plus more in `node_modules`, so make sure you edit the right one):

```
--- a/package.json
+++ b/package.json
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@
   },
   "main": "/index.js",
   "devDependencies": {
-    "react-scripts": "1.0.0"
+    "react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
   },
   "name": "ljg0t8",
   "description": null,
```

That's copying the value already used by `react-scripts` in the `dependencies` section to the instance of `react-scripts` in the `devDependencies` section.

I then ran `npm install`, then `npm start` and everything worked.

(When running `npm start`, I was prompted to add browser compatibility info to `package.json`. Saying yes did that automatically.)

Answer (score 0):

I just would wrap it in a "div" tag v.s. having an empty such as is suggested in the tutorial.

Example:

```
import React from "react";

export default function Square() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button className="square">X</button>
      <button className="square">X</button>
      <button className="square">X</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This was the work around I used to keep going on. Seems like a bug with JSX at compilation.