# When i use react-router Navigate Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

[image]
When I learned permission routing in react-router, navigate dealt with the jump issue
Navigate component throw an error Unexpected token, expected "," Why display symbol problems?

Detailed errors are shown on the picture above,Could someone help me with this

This is the source code of the error file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const IsAuth = () => {
  if (true) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }
};
export default IsAuth;
```

i use IsAuth.jsx in index.tsx

```
import IsAuth from './Login/IsAuth';
const createRoutes = (
(xxxxxx)=>{
...
    return (
        <IsAuth>
         <Routes>
         <Routes/>
        <IsAuth/>
    );
}
)
export default createRoutes;
```

Comment: How is your build configured? Do you expect JSX only inside `.jsx` files? (if so: note that your code is inside a vanilla `.js` file)

Comment: How do you use `IsAuth`?

Comment: i import IsAuth in index.tsx  import IsAuth from './Login/IsAuth'; wrap the Routes with IsAuth

Comment: From the logs, I see you've a js file as IsAuth.js with JSX in it. Try changing the filename to IsAuth.jsx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected token at \`>\` of a \`<>\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75368559/unexpected-token-at-of-a)

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

- The `IsAuth` component is a file with a `*.js` file extension so it appears your project has been configured to only expect JSX in `*.jsx`|`*.tsx` files. rename the file to `IsAuth.jsx`.
- `IsAuth` isn't returning the `children` prop to render the wrapped components.

## Solution

- Rename to `IsAuth.jsx`
- Return `children` for the authenticated pathway.

IsAuth.jsx

```
const IsAuth = ({ children }) => {
  return /* authenticated condition */
    ? children
    :  <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router-dom then use link instead of navigate.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, useLocation, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
const IsAuth = () => {
  if (true) {
    return <Link to="/login" />;
  }
};
export default IsAuth;
```

In other cases you can use this way.
First you take a variable and import useNavigate than you use this variable name. Example: const navigate = useNavigate(). You can try it.

Comment: i try this, it didn't work , the same error  :(

Comment: i use return <Link to="/login" />; the same error :(

Comment: the same error :(

Comment: Add your codes here

Comment: Reedited in the question :）